# Probability density function and expectation of $1000e^{Z\sqrt{5}}$ where $Z$~$N(0,1)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, density-function

The title is self-contained, I'm trying to calculate the PDF of $1000e^{Z\sqrt{5}}$ where $Z$~$N(0,1)$, and the goal is to get the expectation.

The only source I found online that demonstrates how to derive the PDF of a function of a random variable is page 16 of this link: [http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~pettit/MTH5122/chapter2.pdf](http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/%7Epettit/MTH5122/chapter2.pdf)

Letting $Y = 1000e^{Z\sqrt{5}}$ and following the calculation described in that link (a bit too tedious to type here in its entirety) I get:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\frac{1}{y \sqrt{5}} e^{-\frac{(\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}ln(\frac{y}{1000}))^2}{2}{}}$$

Is it possible to validate this? If this is incorrect, is there a suggestion or a source you can point me to to help me figure out this density.

Alternatively, maybe there is a way to calculate the expectation of $V(Z)$ through the density of $Z$ directly, but I don't see how that's possible.

Comment: Searching "exp normal distribution" gave me [this result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1000 is not a problem because it is a constant and thus $E(1000X)=1000E(X)$ and $V(1000X)=1000^2V(X)$

It is very easy to prove that

$$Y=Z\sqrt{5}\sim N(0;5)$$

It is well known that $e^Y$ has a [lognormal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) thus the problem is solved. You can calculate whatever you want given that the random law is known

In the enclosed link (at the paragraph **Characteristic function and moment generating function**) there is a very easy and quick proof to get all the simple moments of your rv